# Set the background of an variable specific item in a Grid

Tags: grid-layouts, style

I have a Grid in which I want to modify the background of the minimum value of the last row. For that purpose, I have create a variable with the position of the minimum value of this row "PosicionECMMin = Position[ECMEst, Min[ECMEst]]" but that does not work. Can anyone help me. I attached an image where you can see what I want. Thank you very much.

[image: Set the background minimum value of the last row]

```
{EspEst, VarEst, ECMEst} = RandomReal[1, {3, 4}]
PosicionECMMin = Position[ECMEst, Min[ECMEst]]


Grid[{{"", 
"T1", 
"T2", 
"T3", 
"T4"}, 
Prepend[EspEst, "Esperanza"], Prepend[VarEst, "Varianza"], 
Prepend[ECMEst, "ECM"]}, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Center, 
Spacings -> 2, 
Background -> {None, None, {4, PosicionECMMin + 1} -> Green}]
```

Comment: ECMEst has numeric values as you can see in the image that I have attached. To see the value of the "PosicionECMMin" I have printed his value and I have seen that It is correct but when I put this variable into the Background code, it does not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You got the position specification wrong. `PosicionECMMin + 1` in your answer is not the scalar it is supposed to be.

As M. Stern points out, the most straightforward way to fix this is to replace

```
PosicionECMMin = Position[ECMEst, Min[ECMEst]]
```

in your code, with

```
PosicionECMMin = Position[ECMEst, Min[ECMEst]][[1, 1]]
```

This also works:

```
{EspEst, VarEst, ECMEst} = RandomReal[1, {3, 4}];
PosicionECMMin = 
  Prepend[FirstPosition[ECMEst, Min[ECMEst]], 4] + {0, 1};

Grid[{
  {"", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"},
  Prepend[EspEst, "Esperanza"],
  Prepend[VarEst, "Varianza"],
  Prepend[ECMEst, "ECM"]
  },
 Frame -> All,
 Alignment -> Center,
 Spacings -> 2,
 Background -> {None, None, PosicionECMMin -> Green}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another approach would be to not use the `Background` property, but to use `Item` instead:

```
PosicionECMMin = FirstPosition[ECMEst, Min[ECMEst]];
ECMEst = ReplacePart[ECMEst, 
  PosicionECMMin -> 
   Item[Extract[ECMEst, PosicionECMMin], Background -> Green]]

Grid[{
  {"", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"},
  Prepend[EspEst, "Esperanza"],
  Prepend[VarEst, "Varianza"],
  Prepend[ECMEst, "ECM"]
  },
 Frame -> All,
 Alignment -> Center,
 Spacings -> 2
 ]
```

The `Item` approach can also be used with `TableForm`:

```
{EspEst, VarEst, ECMEst} = RandomReal[1, {3, 4}];
PosicionECMMin = FirstPosition[ECMEst, Min[ECMEst]];
ECMEst = ReplacePart[
   ECMEst,
   PosicionECMMin -> Item[Extract[ECMEst, PosicionECMMin], Background -> Green]
   ];

TableForm[
 {EspEst, VarEst, ECMEst},
 TableHeadings -> {{"Esperanza", "Varianza", "ECM"}, {"T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Beware that the `Item` approach modifies `ECMEst`. If you intend to keep doing other work with `ECMEst` then you'll want to copy the values to another variable first.

Comment: or simply add `[[1,1]]` after `Position[ECMEst, Min[ECMEst]]`

Comment: @M.Stern In OP's original version, yes. Not in my versions.

Comment: Yes. Now that I think about it.. using FirstPosition is better in general